# JQuery/AJAX/PHP Error in Chrome Only: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, jquery

Using jQuery to make an AJAX call to a PHP file results in the following error in Chrome only: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

jQuery Snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/Test_Get.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        ID: settings.ID
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('ok');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
        console.log('error');
    });
```

PHP Snippet:

```
...
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

require_once('../classes/Database.php');
require_once('../classes/Test.php');
...
```

I spent hours researching this issue and there are a few posts on stackoverflow that talk about problem characters etc. but I haven't been able to solve this.

The specific problem here appears to be having another `<?php` block on the page (whether it be as part of an include file or added directly to the page).  So because the Test.php file has a `<?php` block in it I can't include this class.  Other browsers work just fine but not Chrome.

The only bad work around I've been able to find is to copy and paste the class code directly within the existing `<?php` block on the page.  This just doesn't seem right -- there must be something fundamental I'm missing here.

Comment: what's your json result?  could the issue be similar to this? http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=616

Comment: Thanks - interesting read.  Characters was the first thing I investigated in both data and code.  However, I can hard code a json result with standard characters and still get the same error.  I can also add a couple of php tags (with no code) and still get the error.  So it isn't a data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a single space before the opening php tag in the include file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not correct, check your error function, the console.log('error'); instruction is outside any scope.
It should be:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/Test_Get.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            ID: settings.ID
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error');
        }
});
```

Comment: Replaced console.log with an alert and got the same error.  What's strange is the json data (as shown in network tab) looks fine. But the $.ajax calls the error function on complete instead of success.

Comment: @user464435: did you see what I stated in my answer? At least in your question the $.ajax definition does not have the correct syntax. You can see that the console.log('error') statement is outside the error's scope.

Comment: Yes - I removed the console.log and it made no difference.  Spent another couple of hours on this but still haven't made any progress.  It's a Facebook app in an iframe but that shouldn't make any difference either.  Very strange!